# how to configure VSCode to use oh-my-zsh in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to configure `oh-my-zsh` as integrated terminal for my vscode.

Bellow is my user configuration

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 12,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/zsh"
}
```

But whenever I try to open integrated terminal it throws an error saying 
`The terminal process command '/bin/zsh' failed to launch (exit`

```
OS : Ubuntu 18.04
VSCode : 1.26.1
```

Output of `echo $SHELL` is `/bin/zsh`

I also tried with value `zsh` and `/usr/bin/zsh` but got the same error.

The same works for `/bin/bash`

What else I need to do?

Comment: Did you quit Code and restart after making the line /bin/zsh?  I tried it on my Mac but I had to restart VScode for the change to take effect.

Comment: I did, but didn't worked.

Comment: After all try I did a reinstall of VSCode and yes!! now its working.

Answer (score 4):

to solve your problem, run the command in your terminal

`which zsh`

Then in VSC , replace the

`"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/zsh"`

with

`"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "{the location your terminal pointed to}"`

Answer (score 0):

In **Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)** do:

1. Start *VSCode*
2. Press `F1`
3. Type `user settings`
4. click on button *open settings json*
5. Edit or add the lines:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/usr/local/bin/zsh",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "-c",
    "zsh"
],
```

6. Restart *VSCode*